# Configuring custom Tomcat configuration folder

Tags: tomcat

In Apache Tomcat the traditional home of all configuration files is the ${catalina.home/base}/conf folder.

Can we configure a custom folder within our file system (may be outside the CATALINA_HOME/BASE) to act as the configuration home of Tomcat? If yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot split off the `conf` directory. Usually what you do - and what's suggested by Tomcat documentation - is you have a single "binary" installation of tomcat, pointed to by `CATALINA_HOME`, and one or possibly several "personal" instances each having a `conf`, `webapps` and so on are. This would be pointed to by `CATALINA_BASE`. So to answer your question: set an environment variable `CATALINA_BASE` underneath which you can have your "external" configuration directory.

For completeness, here is the relevant info from the file `RUNNING.txt` under the Tomcat installation:

> In many circumstances, it is desirable to have a single copy of a
>   Tomcat binary distribution shared among multiple users on the same
>   server.  To make this possible, you can set the $CATALINA_BASE
>   environment variable to the directory that contains the files for your
>   'personal' Tomcat instance.
>
> When you use $CATALINA_BASE, Tomcat will calculate all relative
>   references for files in the following directories based on the value
>   of $CATALINA_BASE instead of $CATALINA_HOME:
>
> - bin  - Only setenv.sh (*nix), setenv.bat (windows) and tomcat-juli.jar
> - conf - Server configuration files (including server.xml)
> - logs - Log and output files
> - webapps - Automatically loaded web applications
> - work - Temporary working directories for web applications
> - temp - Directory used by the JVM for temporary files (java.io.tmpdir)
>
> Note that by default Tomcat will first try to load classes and JARs
>   from $CATALINA_BASE/lib and then $CATALINA_HOME/lib. You can place
>   instance specific JARs and classes (eg JDBC drivers) in
>   $CATALINA_BASE/lib whilst keeping the standard Tomcat JARs in
>   $CATALINA_HOME/lib.
>
> If you do not set $CATALINA_BASE, $CATALINA_BASE will default to the
>   same value as $CATALINA_HOME, which means that the same directory is
>   used for all relative path resolutions.